# Second-level cache: cache the non-existence of a database record with a given key?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching, hazelcast, second-level-cache

I have a rarely-changed table that I'd like to keep in the 2nd level cache. I need to eliminate the database round trip both in the case when the record exists (in which case it's a standard use for `@CacheResult`) as well when it doesn't. I preload the cache with the records that exist so if an entity is not in the cache, it's not in the database either (of course, it would not have worked otherwise). I checked [CacheMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/CacheMode.html) but no option is applicable.

In other words, the question is how to get the 2nd level cache store a `CacheEntry` for a null entity.